# SonarQube gate failed even though coverage is 100%

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

We have been stuck with an issue with SonarQube. 
The gate says fail with huge difference of coverage % but the coverage when you click it is 100%. Jacoco is at around 90% Total.

What are we missing here?

[image]
[image]

Tech stack: Java 1.8, Spring boot 1.5.10, SonarQube Scan plugin 3.4.0.905, & Jacoco 0.8.1.
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify the correct version of SonarQube ? Because SonarQube 3.4.0.905 doesn't exist.
Could you also send us a screenshot of the quality gate configuration ?

Comment: Ah sorry that was the plugin,
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905

Added SonarQube version and Quality Gate

Comment: I see that you are using SonarQube 5.6, which is 2 years old, so I think it will be hard to provide you some help. You should consider upgrade to 6.7

Comment: I will suggest this, but 2 years is not too long imo.

Comment: SonarQube 6.7 is latest LTS, I've forgotten to specify this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the application in SonarQube and re submitting solved the issue.