# SonarQube QUALITY GATE STATUS for a project : "failed"

Tags: sonarqube

[image]

Where can I check the reason?
I have no idea how to make failed to succeeded.

Comment: Your quality gate is failed.
Rule is given right below the RED highlighted Failed status - `Coverage on new code is less than 80%`. So check quality gate attached to the project and change thresholds accordingly.

Comment: Apply this solution your problem will be fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747979/sonarqube-gate-failed-even-though-coverage-is-100

Comment: Apply this solution your problem will be fixed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747979/sonarqube-gate-failed-even-though-coverage-is-100